# Multiple Many-to-many bi-directional self-inner-joins without repeating whole query

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

I have a data model such that items can have many-to-many relationships with other items in the same table using a second table to define relationships.  Let's call the primary table `items`, keyed by `item_id` and the relationships table `item_assoc` with columns `item_id` and `other_item_id` and `assoc_type`.  Generally, you might use a `union` to pick up on relationships that may be defined in either direction in the `item_assoc` table, but you would wind up repeating other parts of the same query just to be sure to pick up associations defined in either direction.

Let's say that you're trying to put together a fairly complex query similar to the following where you want to find a list of items that have related items that COULD have associated cancellation items, but select those that do not have cancellation items:

```
select 
  orig.*
from items as orig

join item_assoc as orig2related
  on orig.item_id = orig2related.item_id
join items as related
  on orig2related.other_item_id = related.item_id
 and orig2related.assoc_type = 'Related'

left join item_assoc as related2cancel
  on related.item_id = related2cancel.item_id
left join items as cancel
  on related2cancel.other_item_id = cancel.item_id
 and related2cancel.assoc_type = 'Cancellation'

where cancel.item_id is null
```

This query obviously only picks up items whose relationships are defined in one direction.  For a less complex query, I might solve this by adding a `union` at the bottom for every permutation of the reverse relationships, but I think that would make the query unnecessarily long and hard to understand.

Is there a way I can define both directions of each relationship without repeating the other parts of the query?

Comment: What if you add an OR to your joins conditions and perhaps to the WHERE conditions with the reverse conditions?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  It's a long story and distracting from the issue at hand.

Comment: @kiks73 OR clauses on the joins themselves cause me to select duplicate rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The example is contrived--it doesn't matter which database it runs on.  My actual databases happen to be Oracle, mysql, AND a postgres-derivative and run a query just like this without issue.

Comment: @IronSavior and what about a SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: @kiks73 I would rather not use `distinct`.  It's broken my heart in the past.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I appreciate your keen eye for detail and your stewardship of SO.  I'm not just throwing around tags for the sake of tagging all the things, we're actually using all of these DBs.  I put `as` in there simply because I think it's more readable--for platforms that don't support `as`, just close your eyes and imagine it isn't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UNION within item_assoc could help. Assuming you have a DB without a WITH clause you would have to define a view

```
CREATE VIEW bidirec_item_assoc AS
(
SELECT item_id, other_item_id, assoc_type, 1 as direction FROM item_assoc
UNION
SELECT other_item_id, item_id, assoc_type, 2 as direction FROM item_assoc
)
```

You can now use `bidirec_item_assoc` in your queries where you have used `items_assoc` before.

***Edited Out:*** You could add columns for direction and relationtype, of course

Comment: Changing the schema or imposing rules for how data gets put into the database is not possible in my case.  I just want to make a readable query for the situation I inherited.

Comment: @Iron Savior: There is no need to change the database here. Add `WITH bidirec_item_assoc AS (<here the proposed query>)` in front of your query, then simply use `bidirec_item_assoc` instead of `item_assoc`. Nice solution!

Comment: That's not what I proposed. I have proposed using a view which unifies the table with itself but switching the columns, therefore giving you one base for your queries. The columns shall be added to the query, of course. I'll flesh it out a bit

Comment: @Roland I'm less familiar with these aspects of sql.  I would be very interested in seeing what you have.

Comment: @Roland I was actually able to use the `with` form with our pgsql and it seems to help in the case where I refer to the cte only once.  I think it has something to do with the fact that I'm looking for Items with related items that don't have subsequently related cancellation items.  Thanks for the insight here!

Answer (score 1):

Simplify, simplify, simplify: Don't involve tables in the query that aren't needed.

The following query should be equivalent to your sample query and more expressive of your intent:

```
select i.*
from items i
where not exists ( select *
                   from item_assoc r
                   join item_assoc c on c.item_id    = r.item_id
                                    and c.assoc_type = 'Cancellation'
                   where r.item_id    = i.item_id
                     and r.assoc_type = 'Related'
                 )
```

It should select the set of items that aren't related to an item that has been cancelled. There's not need to join against the items table 3 times.

Further, your original query will have duplicate rows: every row in the first item table (`orig`) will be duplicated once for every related item.

Comment: I agree with what you say here, but it doesn't address the question.  The question is more about the relationships in `item_assoc` being bi-directional.  In my case, the original item's `item_id` is not guaranteed to be in the `item_assoc.item_id` column, it may be in the `item_assoc.other_item_id` column.  (I'm not the one who let that happen, I'm just the one that has to work around it.)